# Java Multiline Input

Tags: java, jcreator

I am trying to solve an online programming problem (Here it is: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1002).  
 However, whenever i try the first input data as:

```
7325189087        (a call number to decipher)
20                (total number of words to input)
...               (input here Words up to 20 lines)
```

The Java console doesn't respond/hangs after the 20th line. Can anyone help me point where the error is occurring? I tried both Scanner and BufferedReader, as well as on Windows command prompt and JCreator's command line, but to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class PhoneNumbers {

    static List<String> cmb = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> indices = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((System.in)));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
        String inp = "";
        while(true) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            inp = in.nextLine();
            if(inp.equals("-1")) break;
            System.out.print(" ");
            int loops = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            //String[] words = new String[loops];
            List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++){
                System.out.print(" ");
                words.add(in.nextLine());       //Error occurs here. if loop is 20 line or more.
            }
            String nums = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
                nums += i;
            Combi("",nums,words,inp.length());
            boolean isfound = false;
            String ind = "";
            int len = 100;
            for(int i = 0; i < cmb.size(); i++){
                String result = "";
                for(int i2 = 0; i2 < cmb.get(i).length(); i2++) {   
                    result += getVal((cmb.get(i).charAt(i2) + "").toLowerCase());
                }
                if(inp.equals(result)) {
                    isfound = true;
                    int len2 = indices.get(i).length();
                    if(len2 < len){
                        len = len2;
                        ind = indices.get(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isfound){
                String out = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < ind.length(); i++) {
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(ind.charAt(i) + "");
                    out += words.get(x);
                    if(i < ind.length() - 1)
                        out += " ";
                }
                outputs.add(out);
            }
            else
                outputs.add("No solution.");
            cmb.clear();
            indices.clear();
        }

        cmb.clear();
        indices.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < outputs.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(outputs.get(i));
    }

    public static void Combi(String pre, String s, List<String> col, int len) {
        if(!pre.equals("")){
            String nval = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < pre.length(); i++){
                nval += col.get(Integer.parseInt(pre.charAt(i) + ""));
            }
            if(nval.length() == len){
                cmb.add(nval);
                indices.add(pre);
                Perm("",pre,col,len);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            Combi(pre + s.charAt(i), s.substring(i + 1),col,len);
    }

    public static void Perm(String pre, String s, List<String> col, int len) {
        int n = s.length();
        if(n == 0){
            String nval = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < pre.length(); i++){
                nval += col.get(Integer.parseInt(pre.charAt(i) + ""));
            }
            if(cmb.contains(nval) == false){
                cmb.add(nval);
                indices.add(pre);
            }
        } else{
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                Perm(pre + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0,i) + s.substring(i + 1, n),col,len);
        }
    }

    public static int getVal(String ltr) {
        if (ltr.equals("i") || ltr.equals("j"))
            return 1;
        if (ltr.equals("a") || ltr.equals("b") || ltr.equals("c"))
            return 2;
        if (ltr.equals("d") || ltr.equals("e") ||ltr.equals("f"))
            return 3;
        if(ltr.equals("g") || ltr.equals("h"))
            return 4;
        if (ltr.equals("k") || ltr.equals("l"))
            return 5;
        if (ltr.equals("m") || ltr.equals("n"))
            return 6;
        if (ltr.equals("p") || ltr.equals("r") || ltr.equals("s"))
            return 7;
        if (ltr.equals("t") || ltr.equals("u") || ltr.equals("v"))
            return 8;
        if (ltr.equals("w") || ltr.equals("x") || ltr.equals("y"))
            return 9;
        if (ltr.equals("o") || ltr.equals("q") || ltr.equals("z"))
            return 0;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

P.S. - I apologize if my codes is still not that efficient. I'm still practicing :D
     
- There are some System.Print(" ") because JCreator's console is quite bugged handling inputs without print something first.

 - I do not ask for helps about this problem. I just ask why Java hangs on the 20th line without any reason.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Learn, please, to use a debugger. Eclipse and IntelliJ are free and include them.

Comment: There are no indications of bugs whatever. Java simply stops responding/getting inputs.

Comment: @JohnEspiritu a debugger will at least tell you _where_ it hangs

Comment: So set breakpoints and step through it to see where your code gets stuck. It's either looping or waiting.

Comment: It may simply be taking too long to complete. With a large number of possible words to search, it has to iterate through so many loops, so many times, that with anything other than a small list, it's not efficient. It gets stuck in a loop in Combi, calling itself over and over.

Comment: @user1886739 - well yeah I guess it is really on the recursion itself. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Without stepping through it with a debugger, I would guess that the code hangs on this line:

```
inp = in.nextLine();
```

Is the 20th line "-1"? If not, then this is most certainly where it hangs, as there are no other ways to exit the `while(true)` loop. If it is, ensure you're entering the data correctly, and that when the "-1" line is reached, the value of `inp` is exactly `"-1"`, not `"-1\n"` or something similar.

I suggest adding a print statement to your while loop that simply prints the value of each `inp` read in, or follow what others suggested and step through the debugger.

Comment: unfortunately, the problem's not there. thanks anyways for the help.